# How do Rust lifetimes interact with &str?

Tags: rust, scope, lifetime

I'm just starting to learn Rust, and I tried typing down the following functions.

```rust
fn longest<'a>(a: &'a str, b: &'a str) -> &'a str{
    if a.len() > b.len() {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "hi";
    let c: &str;
    {
        let b = "nooooo";
        c = longest(a, b);
    }
    print!("{c}");
}
```

Why does the code compile and print "nooooo"? Shouldn't `b`'s lifetime end in the inner scope, why can we still use `c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals has a `'static` lifetime. It doesn't matter that `b` is dropped at the end of the inner scope, because **value** `"nooooo"` lives for the lifetime of the program (as it is stored in the binary itself). Problem will occur, when you for example allocate `String` on heap and then take a reference to it, which will have a shorter lifetime:

```rust
fn longest<'a>(a: &'a str, b: &'a str) -> &'a str{
    if a.len() > b.len() {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "hi";
    let c: &str;
    {
        let b = String::from("nooooo");
        c = longest(a, &b);
    }
    print!("{c}");
}
```

This will fail to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:24
   |
13 |         let b = String::from("nooooo");
   |             - binding `b` declared here
14 |         c = longest(a, &b);
   |                        ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
15 |     }
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
16 |     print!("{c}");
   |             --- borrow later used here
```